# How to catch DatabaseError in Flutter Firebase App

Tags: firebase, flutter, exception, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am learning Flutter and I want to catch the exception that should be thrown ( as security rule is correctly rejecting it) at the Flutter Application/device.

Below is the code

```
   try {
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        try {
        debugPrint(snapshot.toString());
        }
        on DatabaseError catch (eIn1) {
        debugPrint(' onRoot ' + eIn1.toString());
        }
      });
    }on DatabaseError catch (eOut1) {
      debugPrint(' on1 ' + eOut1.toString());
    }

    try {
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("todo").once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        try {
          debugPrint(snapshot.toString());
        }
        on DatabaseError catch (eIn2) {
          debugPrint(' onNode ' + eIn2.toString());
        }
      });
    }on Exception catch (eOut2) {
      debugPrint(' on2 ' + eOut2.toString());
    }
```

But the Exception is never thrown or catch by the Android Studio, In logCat I can see the exception,

> com.example.flutterlogindemo E/flutter:
>   [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception:
>   DatabaseError(-3, Permission denied, )
>       #0      Query.once (package:firebase_database/src/query.dart:84:41)
>       
>       #1      _HomePageState.initState (package:flutter_login_demo/pages/home_page.dart:48:65)

but could not find a away to catch it in code and then act on the exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `catchError` to be able to catch the error:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("todo").once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    print(snapshot);
})
.catchError((error) {
    print("Something went wrong: ${error.message}");
  });
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-async_async/DelegatingFuture/catchError.html

Answer (score 0):

***Repeating my answer to [Flutter: PlatformException thrown by FireBase won't get caught](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60815495/flutter-platformexception-thrown-by-firebase-wont-get-caught/65576481#65576481) here:***

The `try catch` blocks will work if the Firebase call is within an `async` function and the `await` statement is used when calling Firebase.

For example, in the following code an error getting the token will be trapped by the `on PlatformException catch (...` block but an error writing the token to FB RTDB won't be:

```
  Future<void> _saveDeviceToken() async {
    try {
      final _currentUser = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
      final fcmToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
      if (fcmToken != null) {
        // Save the token to Firebase - NO AWAIT STATEMENT
        globals.firebaseDatabase
            .reference()
            .child("pushTokens")
            .child("${_currentUser.uid}")
            .set({"token": fcmToken});
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (error, stackTrace) {
      print("error: $error");
    }
  }
```

whereas adding the `await` statement, as in the following code, will trap errors in writing to FB RTDB as well:

```
  Future<void> _saveDeviceToken() async {
    try {
      final _currentUser = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
      final fcmToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
      if (fcmToken != null) {
        // Save the token to Firebase - AWAIT STATEMENT ADDED
        await globals.firebaseDatabase
            .reference()
            .child("pushTokens")
            .child("${_currentUser.uid}")
            .set({"token": fcmToken});
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (error, stackTrace) {
      print("error: $error");
    }
  }
```

If you don't want to or can't use `await` then, as per Peter's answer, the solution is to use the `catchError` statement instead of `try catch`.