# firebase_auth: throws PlatfromException instead of FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException when user is disabled?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

FlutterSDK:1.12.13+hotfix.7

this my simple code :

```
final PhoneVerificationCompleted phoneVerificationCompleted =
        (AuthCredential credential) async{
          print("verified $phoneNumber");


         try{
                await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

                } on PlatformException catch (exception){
                  print(exception);

                } catch (error){

                }
```

it works fine until i try to disable the account from Firebase Console .
according to firebase docs FirebaseAuth should throw FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException
no matter what i still can't handle this thrown PlatFormException .
and this is what i get when a disabled user try to login .

```
[ +876 ms] E/flutter ( 2479): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception:
PlatformException(ERROR_USER_DISABLED, The user account has been disabled by an administrator., null)
[ +4 ms] E/flutter ( 2479): #0 StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
[ +29 ms] E/flutter ( 2479): #1 MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:33)
[ +2 ms] E/flutter ( 2479):
[ +17 ms] E/flutter ( 2479): #2 MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:349:48)
[ +4 ms] E/flutter ( 2479): #3 MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential
(package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:161:23)
[ +19 ms] E/flutter ( 2479): #4 FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:208:10)
[ +2 ms] E/flutter ( 2479): #5 _RegisterUiState.verifyNumber.
(package:highest_price/ui/register_ui.dart:47:45)
[ +1 ms] E/flutter ( 2479): #6 MethodChannelFirebaseAuth._callHandler
(package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:377:30)
[ +1 ms] E/flutter ( 2479): #7 MethodChannel._handleAsMethodCall (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:402:55)
[ ] E/flutter ( 2479): #8 MethodChannel.setMethodCallHandler.
(package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:370:54)
[ +1 ms] E/flutter ( 2479): #9 _DefaultBinaryMessenger.handlePlatformMessage
(package:flutter/src/services/binding.dart:200:33)
[ +3 ms] E/flutter ( 2479): #10 _invoke3. (dart:ui/hooks.dart:303:15)
[ +1 ms] E/flutter ( 2479): #11 _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
[ +19 ms] E/flutter ( 2479): #12 _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
[ +1 ms] E/flutter ( 2479): #13 _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
[ ] E/flutter ( 2479): #14 _invoke3 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:302:10)
[ ] E/flutter ( 2479): #15 _dispatchPlatformMessage (dart:ui/hooks.dart:162:5)
[ ] E/flutter ( 2479):
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `catchError` which will let you catch asynchronous code errors:

```
final PhoneVerificationCompleted phoneCompleted =  (AuthCredential credential) {
                FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential).then((data){
                  print(data);
                }).catchError((error){
                  print(error);
                });
           };
```

Check the docs:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-async_async/DelegatingFuture/catchError.html

Comment: actually my code was written the same logic you did , and still PlatformException thrown and can't be handled no matter what :\
it's seems you didn't get the idea , it should throw FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException , but instead we got PlatformException which for some reason it can't be handled  ...

Comment: remove the try catch

Comment: remove the try catch ??? try was made because of the exception which thrown by FireBaseAuth , i don't understand what is in your head .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59978750/how-to-catch-databaseerror-in-flutter-firebase-app

Comment: i can print error if i use .catch error for the future variable , but the vscode debugger still gives uncaught PlatfromException with the messages says 'the use has been disabled by Adminstration' this error i want to catch and print !