# Flutter: PlatformException thrown by FireBase won't get caught

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have a function that is used to sign in to Firebase using firebase_auth, however, whenever an exception is thrown it isn't getting caught and still appears in the Android Studio console nor do the print statements in the catch block ever run.

How do I fix this?

```
signIn({String email, String password}) {
    print('listened');
    try {
      FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
    }
    on PlatformException catch (signUpError) {
      print(signUpError.code);
      if (signUpError.code == 'ERROR_WEAK_PASSWORD') {

        print('Weak Password');

      }else if(signUpError.code=='ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND'){
        print('Invalid Username');
      }

      else{
        print(signUpError.toString());
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

`signInWithEmailAndPassword` returns a `Future<AuthResult>` (it is asynchronous), therefore you need to use the `catchError` method to catch the error when calling an asynchronous method:

```
 FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password).then((result) {
    print(result);
})
.catchError((error) {
    print("Something went wrong: ${error.message}");
  });
```

Check the following:

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.3.0/dart-async/Future/catchError.html

https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-authentication-in-flutter-50e8b81cb29f

Comment: So the regular try/catch way of handling exceptions doesn't work with asynchronous functions then?

Comment: No you won't be able to catch the expection that way

Comment: The only way is to use catcherror please check the links

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56113778/how-to-handle-firebase-auth-exceptions-on-flutter)   and on other stackoverflow links, try/catch was successful in catching exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The `try catch` blocks will work if the Firebase call is within an `async` function and the `await` statement is used when calling Firebase.

For example, in the following code an error getting the token will be trapped by the `on PlatformException catch (...` block but an error writing the token to FB RTDB won't be:

```
  Future<void> _saveDeviceToken() async {
    try {
      final _currentUser = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
      final fcmToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
      if (fcmToken != null) {
        // Save the token to Firebase - NO AWAIT STATEMENT
        globals.firebaseDatabase
            .reference()
            .child("pushTokens")
            .child("${_currentUser.uid}")
            .set({"token": fcmToken});
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (error, stackTrace) {
      print("error: $error");
    }
  }
```

whereas adding the `await` statement, as in the following code, will trap errors in writing to FB RTDB as well:

```
  Future<void> _saveDeviceToken() async {
    try {
      final _currentUser = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
      final fcmToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
      if (fcmToken != null) {
        // Save the token to Firebase - AWAIT STATEMENT ADDED
        await globals.firebaseDatabase
            .reference()
            .child("pushTokens")
            .child("${_currentUser.uid}")
            .set({"token": fcmToken});
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (error, stackTrace) {
      print("error: $error");
    }
  }
```

If you don't want to or can't use `await` then, as per Peter's answer, the solution is to use the `catchError` statement instead of `try catch`.